# I've killed the Wall of Flesh but can't get to the loot

Tags: terraria

I have beaten the Wall of Flesh but can't get to the loot, as I died from the lava just after. The Hardmode enemies are too difficult to kill and do so much damage that I can't get past them to reach the Underworld. Does anyone have any tips or ideas to help me get the loot? Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @HyperDiamondz What weapons, armor, and tools do you have?

Answer (score 8):

While the Pwnhammer is instrumental in getting easy access to hardmode ores, there is another way!

Crates can be fished from the water! These crates have a chance to contain hardmore ores, allowing you access to those more powerful armor and weapon pieces. Depending on if you're playing the PC, Console, or Mobile versions, your access to certain crates may be denied, as the Console and Mobile versions only have Wood, Iron, and Golden crates.

Better bait and better fishing rods will give you greater chances at obtaining crates from your fishing excursions. The Angler's quests will give you access to better rods and bait over time, but these can take some time to complete. Once you're better geared up, you can make your way down to the Underworld to get your WoF loot, and maybe even fight it a few more times.

[Information gained from here.](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crates)

Comment: Have you seriously tried to fish for ores? I tried that on once, by the time I have enough for a copper armour I have a lifetime supply of fish XD

Comment: Can't imagine fishing for Titanium...

Comment: @BenOng Can't imagine mining Titanium with the Molten Pickaxe. That is not the first level of ore in hardmode, so you obviously don't fish for that.

Comment: @Tom you actually can, crates in hardmode have a chance of giving either variant of the three initial tiers of hardmode ores/bars if you are lucky, but the ores/bars given is quite random, plus the chance that it might not even give ores/bars, plus the chance that you might not even get a create fishing... it will really a take long time, but can be done.

Comment: @BenOng You haven't understood my comment. You can get Titanium, but that isn't your main target. You aim for Cobald or Palladium Ore.

Comment: @Tom i actually think otherwise, if you can get enough for a Titanium/Adamantium drill plus enough Orichalcum/Mythril to make an anvil, you can freely harvest all three initial hardmode ores.

Comment: @BenOng You make valid points, but the user is attempting to survive in the Underworld long enough to get their WoF loot, not to make an Adamantium drill.

Comment: @BenOng As Kaizerwolf said, this was not the point of this question and I don't think that you'll be faster fishing for hardmode ore instead of using the "normal way" after retrieving the Pwnhammer.

Comment: While it is not a direct answer, but I think having an alternative to not retrieving the pwnhammer that is currently out of reach isn't that bad an idea, in fact I'll make it a formal answer!

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way to reach the Underworld level, post-Wall Of Flesh, is to use a [Hellevator](http://terraria.wikia.com/wiki/Hellevator): basically a straight-vertical two-block hole in the ground, leading all the way from your home base down to the Underworld.  You can buy a bunch of rope from the Merchant to let you go up and down easily.  This lets you avoid monsters because (1) you're moving past them very quickly, and (2) most of them can't get at you through walls.

Usually you build your Hellevator *before* starting Hardmode, but you can probably get it to work afterward if you're careful.  Make sure to line the sides of your Hellevator with blocks -- you don't want monsters wandering in!  There are various ways to deal with pools of water and lava in your path, but my favorite is to drop bombs until it breaks through and drains the water/lava into a cavern somewhere below.

Burrowing and phasing enemies will be a problem for you, especially if you get too close to the Hallow or the Evil biomes.  All I can suggest is to Magic Mirror out and come back when they despawn.

Once you get to the Underworld, things will get easier -- no Hardmode enemies spawn naturally in the Underworld at the start of Hardmode.

Comment: On the last point, if you are right under the part where hallow/crimson/corruption touches the underworld, you may face some hardmode monsters from those biome. That may be hard to avoid due lava. But on the bright side, you have a much more open area to fight those monsters and Soul of Light/Night may drop.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments in Kaizerwolf's answer, I like to offer an alternative to this situation. While a pwnhamer is conveniently dropped by WOF and can destroy the Altars to spawn and increase the amount of the three hardmode initial tier ores, it is not the only means forward.

As per Kaizerwolf's answer, you can obtain the ores and even the bars of the hardmode ores by fishing, I instead suggest that you create a Mythril/Orihalcum Anvil also a Titanium/Adamantium drill/pickaxe, during which you may have enough Cobalt/Palladium for some weapon or armour pieces for going to hell(to retrieve the pwnhammer). This will enable you access to all three tiers of hardmode ores before you go smashing Altars and harvest the larger amount required for weapons and armours.

I'll also introduce a few items that'll make this method more efficient:

1. [Crate Potion](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crate_Potion) as it's name suggest, increase chance of obtaining crates from fishing. I believe it doubles the base chance from 10% to 20%
2. [Sonar Potion](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Sonar_Potion) less effective than crate potion but this allows you to reject junk and common fishes so you waste less baits on those.
3. [Fishing Potion](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Fishing_Potion) downright increases fishing power which in turns slightly increases chance to get crates.
4. [Angler Tackle Bag](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Angler_Tackle_Bag) high tier crates(gold and biomes) get increased chance of appearing when fishing power is high, this accessory will boost fishing power while also letting you use/waste less bait while fishing, it can be obtain even before hardmode but also while you are fishing for your ores, just make sure to do the Angler's quest daily.
5. [Buggy](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Buggy)/[Enchanted Nightcrawler](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Enchanted_Nightcrawler) These two are baits that are not too hard to obtain while having decent fishing power. Buggy can be found in the jungle which is not too dangerous right into hardmode, just break the bushes and one might appear. Enchanted Nightcrawler is just an upgraded Worm by combining it with a Star dropped at night.

For the actual process of reaching the pwnhammer, I have a few tips:

1. Fly, with a [Gravitation Potion](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Gravitation_Potion) or a pair of [Wings](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Wings) even those demon scythe and spears have trouble reaching you.
2. [Calming Potion](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Calming_Potion)/[Peace Candle](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Peace_Candle) using both of these together with Gravitation Potion or Wings, the underworld should be safe enough to move around even in hardmode.
3. If that is still not enough use [Invisibility Potion](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Invisibility_Potion), while under its effect, ranged monsters will not shoot at you. And seriously, if dodging slimes and bats are too hard I have no more solutions to offer.

Additional option from Tom's comment(also mentioned by JonK in comments of the question) is to create another world to fight the WOF in pre hardmode conditions again, this time not making the same mistake.

And if out of world resources is not a taboo for you there are also [world editors](https://terraria.gamepedia.com/Map_viewers) available around that you can use to reset the world into pre hardmode for a retry.

Just take note that if you are playing in your own world once you leave the items will be gone so when you reach that spot again after returning the Demonite or Crimtane bricks will be left.

Comment: Why do I think my answer makes more sense if I flip it around and provide means to reach the pwnhammer first? XD

Comment: Now we have 4 answers and no one just said: create a new world and kill the Wall there ^^. Do you might want to add that as another possibility? :D

Comment: There you go, plus a bit more

Comment: Appreciate it :)

Comment: It's funny that your reasoning has gone from "you want to fish for THAT much hardmode ore?!" to "fish for so much hardmode ore that you create anvils and drills!" It makes sense, just seems a little funny on your reasoning!

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation and what I did is made a nice tunnel that the enemies could not shoot/attack me through and got the items, try that :D

Comment: Not a bad idea, but try expanding on it! Your answer is a little thin on content; maybe post a screenshot of what you're talking about to improve your answer!

Answer (score -1):

If you have any teleportation potions, you may be able to use them and get lucky. It's possible to fish up Chaos Fish from the Underground Hallow to make more, but if you aren't able to get there safely, then a hellevator is a good idea. If your usual route to the Underworld is reasonably easy and vertical, applying thorns potions and inferno potions will allow you to damage anything coming near you, as will accessories such as the Honey Comb. If you swing a sword the whole way, with some of the potions, you might just make it, as long as you bring a few healing potions.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you did the long bridge method for WoF you could simply run past the enemies with spectre boots. Or at least rocket boots